# Avoid duplication while testing model attributes in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a several models and in this models I have attributes that I don't want to be blank / empty.

I want to heavily test my models on these restrictions using RSpec and Factory Girl.

However I end up with code duplication:

**user_spec:**

```
it 'is invalid if blank' do
  expect {
   FactoryGirl.create(:user, nickname => '')
  }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
end
```

**message_spec:**

```
it 'is invalid if blank' do
  expect {
   FactoryGirl.create(:message, :re => '')
  }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
end
```

How can I factor it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSpec provides several ways to do so, such as [Shared Examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

**1. Create a file in your `[RAILS_APP_ROOT]/support/`**

Based on your example, you could name this file `not_blank_attribute.rb`. Then, you just have to move your duplicated code in and adapting it to make it configurable :

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'a mandatory attribute' do |model, attribute|
  it 'should not be empty' do
    expect {
      FactoryGirl.create(model, attribute => '')
    }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
  end
end
```

**2. Use `it_behaves_like` function in your specs**

This function will call the shared example.

```
RSpec.describe User, '#nickname' do
  it_behaves_like 'a mandatory attribute', :User, :nickname
end
```

Finally, it outputs:

```
User#nickname
  behaves like a mandatory attribute
      should not be empty
```